# jQuery-Javascript setTimeout-clearTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

In the snippet below, I would like to call the `change()` function only if I have stayed continuously over a `div` for a period of time. If I just skim over the `div`, I would like to cancel out the call to the function - using `clearTimeout`.

I see that the clearTimeout is not working. Someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

jQuery portion :

```
       var obj=$('#aaa');

        var tt;
        obj.find('div').bind({
            mouseenter:function(e){
                var that = $(this)
                tt = setTimeout(function(){
                                    change(e,that)
                                },1000) // <-- time to wait before execution
            },
            mouseleave:function(e){
                clearTimeout(tt);
            }
        });

      function change(e,that){
        console.log(e)
        console.log(that)
      }
```

HTML portion :

```
  <div id='aaa'>
    <div><!--class a start-->
        <div>lkaiseulaweg</div>
        <div><!--class b start-->
            <div>ae</div>
            <div>dd</div>
        </div><!--class b end-->
    </div><!--class a end-->

    <div><!--class a start-->
        <i>numbers</i>
        <div><!--class b start-->
            <div>986</div>
            <div>345</div>
            <div>000</div>
            <div>999</div>
        </div><!--class b end-->

    </div><!--class a end-->
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML element with id `aaa` ?

Comment: There's no element with id #aaa!

Comment: Sorry. That was an error due to stackoverflow. The code is now the way I wanted to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra closure for each div, so that the `tt` variable is unique. Use `.each` to bind event listeners, effectively creating a new closure for each `tt` variable:

```
obj.find('div').each(function(){
    var tt;
    var that = $(this)
        that.bind({
        mouseenter:function(e){
            clearTimeout(tt); // In case something weird happens
            tt = setTimeout(function(){
                                change(e,that)
                            },1000) // <-- time to wait before execution
        },
        mouseleave:function(e){
            clearTimeout(tt);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is somewhat I was looking for. Here I see that the mouseenter/mouseleave propagates. Perhaps inserting stopPropagatoin() helps ?

Comment: @maan81 You can also bind the event listeners to the container, and use `e.target` to check whether the active element is a div or not. That event would only be triggered once.

Comment: I am sorry. You you please provide a example?  :-(

Comment: Example: `$('#aaa').mouseenter(function(e){if($.nodeName(e.target, 'div'){ /* clearTimeout etc */}}).mouseleave(function(e){if($.nodeName(e.target,'div')) {clearTimeout(tt);}})`

Answer (score 1):

Try hover intent which adds delays http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a div with id ='aaa' some where in your HTML

```
<div id='aaa'><!--class a start-->
        <div>lkaiseulaweg</div>
        <div><!--class b start-->
            <div>ae</div>
            <div>dd</div>
        </div><!--class b end-->
    </div><!--class a end-->

    <div><!--class a start-->
        <i>numbers</i>
        <div><!--class b start-->
            <div>986</div>
            <div>345</div>
            <div>000</div>
            <div>999</div>
        </div><!--class b end-->

    </div><!--class a end-->
```

see the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/vR5hJ/

Comment: Had a problem displaying my codes. I have just corrected it. I wanted the id='aaa' as a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you set many timeouts and store them in the same variable so the first one you set will be overwritten by the next and so on. You can check this by removing all divs inside `#aaa` except one and see that it works fine.

What you need to do is clear the old timeout before you set it:

```
            var that = $(this);
            if(tt) clearTimeout(tt);
            tt = setTimeout(function(){
                                change(e,that)
                            },1000) // <-- time to wait before execution
```

Answer (score -1):

First post: you miss a ";" after `var that = $(this)`

OK, seems not a problem... (but jsfiddle don't valid it !)

But for jsfiddle, you need to define `change` function before to use it.
http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/RTSFR/

Comment: Javascript has no requirement of any kind to use semi colons, only line breaks its just far more standard to use semi colons. http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/